# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when doing React tutorial

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Doing a Hacker News Clone tutorial in React and Next.js, but I'm stumbling into a problem. **I have read other questions that are dealing with the same error, but the solutions offered don't work for me.** Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';

const StoryList = ({ stories }) => (
    <div>
        {stories.map(story => (
            <h3 key={story.id}>{story.title}</h3>
        ))}
    </div>
);


export default StoryList;
```

**The error is specifically at line 4 of that, on the first div tag.**

Here is my index page:

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import Error from 'next/error';

import StoryList from '../components/StoryList';

class Index extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        let stories;

        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://node-hnapi.herokuapp.com/news?page=1'
            );
            stories = await response.json();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            stories = []
        }

        return { stories };
    }

    render() {
        const { stories } = this.props;

        if (stories.length === 0) {
            return <Error statusCode={503} />;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hacker News Clone</h1>
                <StoryList storeis={stories} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: Did you ` <StoryList storeis={stories} />` on purpose ? It should be ` <StoryList stories={stories} />`

Comment: Could it be the typo? You are passing the props as `storeis`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have used `storeis` prop and using as `stories`

see this,

```
<div>
    <h1>Hacker News Clone</h1>
    <StoryList storeis={stories} /> // here prop is storeis
</div>
```

and used as this,

```
const StoryList = ({ stories }) => ( // and here using as stories 
    <div>
        {stories.map(story => (
            <h3 key={story.id}>{story.title}</h3>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

make both same.
I feel that was spell mistake.